# How do I turn off JSESSIONID in Tomcat/Spring Boot when I am only sending a redirect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

How do I stop Tomcat from sending `JSESSIONID` cookie when I am only sending a redirect? I don't access `.getSession()` at all.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*")
public void doUrlRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  ...
  if (redirect != null) response.sendRedirect(redirect);
```

Console

```
$ curl -i localhost:8080/aaa                                                                                                                                                                               HTTP/1.1 302
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A38FE0B0703F4241414BD8DEF646A2BA; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/errorNonMobile
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 19:55:49 GMT
```

I tried

```
request.getServletContext().setSessionTrackingModes(Collections.singleton(SessionTrackingMode.URL));
```

But it errored

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   The session tracking modes for context [] cannot be set whilst the context is running

I need session for another path. I cannot turn it off for the whole app. I only want to turn it off for this request handler.

Answer (score 0):

I turned it off by commenting `@Scope` tag on the controller.

```
@Controller
//@Scope("session")
@ApiIgnore
public class MyUrlController implements ErrorController {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_SESSION

```
$ curl -i localhost:8080/aaa
HTTP/1.1 302
Location: http://localhost:8080/errorNonMobile
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 21:26:25 GMT
```